# Send UDP on specific connection in µIP

Tags: c, micro-ip

I'm using uIP on a Tiva C Launchpad board and want to send UDP Packages. But it seems that the uip_buf is not filled when i call the uip_udp_periodic function.

The code looks like this:

```
uint8_t my_udp_buf = {0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC};
uint32_t my_udp_buf_len = 4;

void main(main){
[...]
    uip_ipaddr_t addr;
    struct uip_udp_conn *c;

    uip_ipaddr(&addr, 172,16,23,1);
    c = uip_udp_new(&addr, HTONS(12345)); // setting up a new UDP connection to 172.16.23.1:12345 here

    [...]
    while(42==42){
        uip_udp_conn = c; // set the current connection to our udp connection
        uip_appdata = my_udp_buf; // asssign the uip_appdata pointer to our data pointer
        uip_send(uip_appdata, my_udp_buf_len); // sending the data


        [...]
        // call the periodic function for all UDP connections
        for(ui32Temp = 0; ui32Temp < UIP_UDP_CONNS; ui32Temp++)
        {
            uip_udp_periodic(ui32Temp);
            // --> The uip_len is always 0! why?

            //
            // If the above function invocation resulted in data that
            // should be sent out on the network, the global variable
            // uip_len is set to a value > 0.
            //
            if(uip_len > 0)
            {
                uip_arp_out();
                PacketTransmit(EMAC0_BASE, uip_buf, uip_len);
                uip_len = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question is, do i set the connection correctly? In the header file i cannot find any macro or function to control on which connection i send out the data, so i assume that i need to set the connection pointer. Also do i need to save the data? probably the pointer to uip_appdata is overwritten somewhere else afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like UDP is not well implemented in the bare uIP version. you need to do a lot of manual stuff:

```
        uip_udp_conn = c; // set your connection
        uip_slen = len; // set the length of data to send
        memcpy(&uip_buf[UIP_LLH_LEN + UIP_IPUDPH_LEN], data, len > UIP_BUFSIZE? UIP_BUFSIZE: len); // copy to the buffer
        uip_process(UIP_UDP_SEND_CONN); // tell uip to construct the package

        uip_arp_out(); // attack Ethernet header
        PacketTransmit(EMAC0_BASE, uip_buf, uip_len); // send the package with the Tiva C function
        uip_len = 0; // reset length to 0
```

in the contiki version of uIP is a lot more UDP convenient functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When working with udp and the tiva, I have found that having a seperate function to handle the udp instances works much better. when you run it out of your main function, you will end up having multiple instances and that will cause instability